# Not able to move div using mousemove in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, mousemove, mouseleave

I am trying to move a div with the help of mousemove event.

Here is the code for the same.
https://codepen.io/anurag92/pen/VEoQOZ

```
class ImageMarker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this);
        this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
        this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this);
        this.paint = this.paint.bind(this);
    }

    mouseDown(e) {
        const position = {
            left: this.marker.offsetLeft,
            top: this.marker.offsetTop
        };

        this.hitOffset = {
            x: e.pageX - position.left,
            y: e.pageY - position.top,
            diameter: this.diameter(),
            markerRadius: 10
        };
        this.marker.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
        this.marker.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp);
        this.marker.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    mouseMove(e) {
        this.position = {
            x: e.pageX - this.hitOffset.x,
            y: e.pageY - this.hitOffset.y
        };
        this.position.x = Math.round(this.position.x);
        this.position.y = Math.round(this.position.y);

        this.position.x = Math.min(700 - 1, Math.max(0, this.position.x));
        this.position.y = Math.min(700 - 1, Math.max(0, this.position.y));

        this.paint();
    }

    mouseUp(e) {
        this.marker.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
        this.marker.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp);
        this.marker.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp);
    }

    diameter() {
        return 1;
    }

    paint() {
        if (JSON.stringify(this.paintedPosition) !== JSON.stringify(this.position)) {
            this.paintedPosition = Object.assign({}, this.position);
        }

        if (this.position) {
            this.marker.style.left = `${100 * this.position.x / 700}%`;
            this.marker.style.top = `${100 * this.position.y / 700}%`;
        }
        return this;
    }

    render() {
        this.position = this.position || {
            x: 5,
            y: 5
        };
        this.offset = 0;
        return <div className='outer'
            ref = {ref => {
                this.canvasRef = ref;
            }}
        >
            <div className = 'marker'
                onMouseDown = {event => this.mouseDown(event)}
                ref = {ref => {
                    this.marker = ref;
                }} >
            </div>
        </div>;
    }

}

// export default ImageMarker;



ReactDOM.render(<ImageMarker />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When i move my cursor slowly its working fine, but on fast movement mouseleave gets triggered and as a result div is not able to keep up with the cursor.

Can someone please tell me a potential fix for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could resolve that by attaching the `mouseMove` (and `mouseUp`)to the whole `document` This way they will be fired no matter if the mouse gets out of the element you want to drag.
Just remember to detach the event during `componentWillUnmount` to avoid leaks.

Further more if you want you site to work on mobile you need to attach touch, pointer or drag events. See the [code of the kendo-draggable](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-draggable/tree/develop/src) abstraction for a reference. We are using it in our react components. Bind to the element on `ComponentDidMount` and detach on `ComponentWillUnmount`